# Shared stylesheet is having issues with nav dimensions visibly changing in different views but showing same size in developer tools (chrome)

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm not too sure if my title conveyed the message well enough. Basically, I am designing a portfolio website. I am using SCSS and have virtually the same html across pages for the navigation and footer. The issue is when I change from say the Home view to the about me view, there is a noticeable difference in the size of the navigation link font size and by proxy the ul height. It is also obvious due to the extra space that shows up under the navigation icon. However, when I look at the DOM styles in the developer tools (as stated above, I am mostly using chrome for the beginning design phase), it shows that regardless of the view, the sizes are the same. I hope that makes sense, and please let me know if additional information is needed to figure this out.

```css
nav {
  background: #00334f;
  /* Old browsers */ }
  nav div.page-icon {
    text-align: center; }
  nav div.page-icon img {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%; }
  nav .nav-header-links {
    list-style: none; }
  nav .nav-header-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a:hover {
    background: #b38f00;
    color: black; }
  nav .nav-header-links li div {
    transition: all 1s ease-in; }
  nav .nav-header-links li:hover div {
    display: block; }
  nav .nav-bottom-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    border-top: solid 20px #b38f00;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    display: none; }
  nav div.social-icons {
    height: 100%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 2rem; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10%;
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-left: solid 2px white;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a img {
      width: 70%;
      height: 70%;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 50%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover img {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<nav class="row">
        <div class="page-icon col-1">
          <img src="design/images/Placeholder.png" alt="Devoneous Design Icon"/>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-header-links col-7">
          <li><a href="">Home</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-icons col-4">
            <ul class="social-icons-list">
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/facebook.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/twitter.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/instagram.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/linkedin.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Here is the about me html:

```css
nav {
  float: none;
  background: #00334f;
  /* Old browsers */
  line-height: 150%; }
  nav div.page-icon {
    text-align: center; }
  nav div.page-icon img {
    width: 53%;
    height: 53%; }
  nav .nav-header-links {
    list-style: none; }
  nav .nav-header-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2.5em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a:hover {
    background: #b38f00;
    color: black; }
  nav .nav-header-links li div {
    transition: all 1s ease-in; }
  nav .nav-header-links li:hover div {
    display: block; }
  nav .nav-bottom-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    border-top: solid 20px #b38f00;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    display: none; }
  nav div.social-icons {
    height: 100%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 2em; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10%;
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-left: solid 2px white;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a img {
      width: 70%;
      height: 70%;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 50%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover img {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<body>
<nav class="row">
        <div class="page-icon col-1">
          <img src="design/images/Placeholder.png" alt="Devoneous Design Icon"/>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-header-links col-7">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="">About Me</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-icons col-4">
            <ul class="social-icons-list">
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/facebook.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/twitter.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/instagram.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/linkedin.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </body>
```

Hopefully you can tell, the html is exactly the same and they are both using the same stylesheet. I cant figure out what this is. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: First code snippet doesn't seem to be picking up any styles.

Comment: Thats strange. Ill fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I also figured out that it is just an issue with chrome. It all maintains accross firefox and IE even.

Comment: The padding around each `nav .nav-header-links li a` is different in these two examples-- both a different value and different units.  In the first example padding is set to `3rem`, in the second one it is set to `2.5em`...

Comment: Sorry, thats because I was playing with the padding after I posted this. So the padding 3em is actually the updated number. They are both using the same stylesheet, so they are both set to 3. I didnt think about that when I made that last edit. Will update.

Comment: Sure-- because once I normalize that padding, the only discrepancy I see seems to be the height of the image pushing the text down a bit-- and one image is set to 53% height and width and the other to 60% height and width...

Comment: They are both set to the updated 53% height (the difference is an update issue I made specifically here). The issue isn't in other browsers. Firefox and IE both show the navigation with the same dimensions across pages. Chrome (in the editor) shows the list with all the same dimensions in pixels but visually speaking it is very different. Say Im in the contact page and I click to the about me page. Leaving the cursor where it is after I click. When the about me view loads, instead of the cursor being dead center as it was when I clicked it, it is now in the top right because the links expand.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post doesn't seem to have any changes-- those discrepancies I called out are still present.  I just edited them in my answer here to be normalized at 53% width/height and 3em of padding and also noted an extra line setting the nav line height at 150% in your first snippet.  I commented that out and now they are identical.

Honestly, I am not sure why you are trying to maintain two different sets of nearly identical SCSS for these pages if the html is supposed to be the same-- you might make your life easier by leveraging a single generated stylesheet from sass for all pages that will act as the treatment for all navs, keeping it common across the site.

```css
nav {
  background: #00334f;
  /* Old browsers */ }
  nav div.page-icon {
    text-align: center; }
  nav div.page-icon img {
    width: 53%;
    height:53%; }
  nav .nav-header-links {
    list-style: none; }
  nav .nav-header-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a:hover {
    background: #b38f00;
    color: black; }
  nav .nav-header-links li div {
    transition: all 1s ease-in; }
  nav .nav-header-links li:hover div {
    display: block; }
  nav .nav-bottom-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    border-top: solid 20px #b38f00;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    display: none; }
  nav div.social-icons {
    height: 100%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 2rem; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10%;
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-left: solid 2px white;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a img {
      width: 70%;
      height: 70%;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 50%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover img {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<nav class="row">
        <div class="page-icon col-1">
          <img src="design/images/Placeholder.png" alt="Devoneous Design Icon"/>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-header-links col-7">
          <li><a href="">Home</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="aboutMe.html">About Me</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-icons col-4">
            <ul class="social-icons-list">
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/facebook.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/twitter.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/instagram.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/linkedin.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

```css
nav {
  float: none;
  background: #00334f;
  /* Old browsers */
  /*line-height: 150%;*/ }
  nav div.page-icon {
    text-align: center; }
  nav div.page-icon img {
    width: 53%;
    height: 53%; }
  nav .nav-header-links {
    list-style: none; }
  nav .nav-header-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif; }
  nav .nav-header-links li a:hover {
    background: #b38f00;
    color: black; }
  nav .nav-header-links li div {
    transition: all 1s ease-in; }
  nav .nav-header-links li:hover div {
    display: block; }
  nav .nav-bottom-triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    border-top: solid 20px #b38f00;
    border-right: solid 20px transparent;
    border-left: solid 20px transparent;
    display: none; }
  nav div.social-icons {
    height: 100%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list {
      list-style: none;
      text-align: right;
      padding-right: 2em; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10%;
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-left: solid 2px white;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a img {
      width: 70%;
      height: 70%;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 50%; }
    nav div.social-icons .social-icons-list li a:hover img {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
      transform: rotate(360deg); }
```

```html
<body>
<nav class="row">
        <div class="page-icon col-1">
          <img src="design/images/Placeholder.png" alt="Devoneous Design Icon"/>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-header-links col-7">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="">About Me</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a><div class="nav-bottom-triangle"></div></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-icons col-4">
            <ul class="social-icons-list">
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/facebook.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/twitter.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/instagram.png" /></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img src="design/images/Social/linkedin.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
  </body>
```

Comment: It is a single stylesheet. I just posted each page separately so I included the stylesheet in each snippet. I think I got it figured out. Up vote for all the responses you gave me. I appreciate you taking the time to look into this.

Comment: No problem-- what ended up being the issue on your end?  Once I edited your snippets to match I didn't see any differences between the two.

Comment: I still havent fully figured it out. It seems to be an issue with a way the image get sized. I have the image width and height set at 53% in the stylesheet with no sizes set in the html on any page. But for some reason in the about me view the image changes from  95.11 X 95.11 to 86.46 X 86.46 and the parent div gets smaller as well. I just gotta keep tinkering.